# How to receive parameters in one array when passing arguments as an array to call_user_func_array()

Tags: php, oop

I am sending parameters as an array in second argument but not able to receive as one array in my receiving function, I can receive but one value as one variable so if have 3 parameters I have define three variables in my receiving function.

```
 $this->params[] = 'val1';
 $this->params[] = 'val2';

call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
```

I am expecting array in $param but getting in chunks like $param $param2

```
 public function index( $params )
  {
   echo "<pre>";
   var_dump($param);
  }

 public function index( $param1, $param2 )
  {
   echo $param1;
   echo $param2;
  }
```

Comment: Just wrap ithe arguments in one more array: `call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], [$this->params]);`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson are you going to answer or close?  Looks like you have an answer to post.

Comment: Isn't the alternative to use `call_user_func` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution to your issue is to simply wrap the arguments in another array:

```
call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], [$this->params]);
```

Then it will pass an array as the first argument to your method.